# Deploed Spring Boot application on Tomcat create bad URLS

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, deployment, tomcat8

I have Spring Boot application& It is REST API for mobile app. So it works ok localy, but after deply on tomcat remote server, it have problems.
So, here my app in tomcat application manager

[image]

Here is properites file

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework


spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true
spring.freemarker.suffix= .ftl
# location of the swagger json


spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=aibolitDB
spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
spring.data.mongodb.password=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=aibolitDB
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost

springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-aibolit.html



spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=256MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=256MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

app.url.base=http://aibolitbackend.unitbeandev.com/

ub.vet.jwtSecret= bezKoderSecretKey
ub.vet.jwtExpirationMs= 86400000

logging.level.org.springframework.web = trace
logging.level.org.apache = trace
```

And When
I try to send api request, it gives me an error

[image]

As you can see, it try to find in /AibolitBackend/ path
Here my NGINX properties

```
 location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/AibolitBackend/;
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

What I forgot to set up? Need I add some thing to Tomcat hosts?? And I cant to make it on Base / path, because here will by 3 apps.

Answer (score 1):

You have a weird mix of `try_files` and `proxy_pass` directives in the same location. That doesn't make any sense. Usually to serve static files with nginx and pass other requests to the backend you should use something like

```
location /
    # First attempt to serve request as static file, then pass request to the backend
    root <set_correct_root_for_your_static_files_here!>;
    try_files $uri @tomcat;
}
location @tomcat {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

With `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/AibolitBackend/;` you get any request like `/some/path` transformed to `/AibolitBackend/some/path` before going to the backend. I didn't understand what do you want to achieve with this `/AibolitBackend/` prefix.

Comment: Yes, I want tp wahe an access to rest without /AibolitBackend/. It should be like http://aibolitbackend.unitbeandev.com/public/api/***

Comment: How are requests to the REST API differs from the others? Any request starting with `/public/api` is a REST request?