# Delete certificate in application but still listening HTTPS requests (Nginx manages the certificate)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, nginx, https

I have a Spring Boot application listening on `8443` and I put the certificate as a `.p12` file inside the project. I also added all the `ssl` properties on the `application.yml` and everything worked fine.

I recently moved to another server and now it is `nginx` who is *serving the certificate*, so now I would like to **remove the certificate from the server** (as it is expired, it is signed for the old domain and it doesn't seem to be used). I removed the `server.ssl.*` properies but that made the application expect HTTP in that port and throwing `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name.` when accesed.

Is there any way to only use **one** certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: In favor of generalization let's call "`nginx`" your "`proxy server`"
and "`Spring Boot` (actually `Tomcat`)" your "`application`"

**This is what it is happening:**

The client is encrypting the request with the `proxy server`'s certificate you are using, and then the `proxy server` is decrypting it and using the `application` certificate (which can be expired or/and with a wrong domain and still being trusted in by nginx as it is a local forwarding) to encrypt the request.

This process feels transparent for the client, and it will show the `proxy server`'s certificate in the browser, but internally **both are used**.

In order to remove the certificate from the `application`, you need to forward the incoming HTTPS trafic into the internal HTTP port (8080 by default in `Tomcat`).

Here's an example with `nginx`:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;

        include https.conf; #Your certificate configuration

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/ #Your application listening on HTTP
         }
}
```

This way, the client will use the `proxy server`'s certificate, and the `proxy server` itself will comunicate with your application though HTTP.

Comment: Moreover, when you proxy your requests to some other port of the same physical server it is completely meaningless to encrypt the traffic that goes only via local network interface. The only thing it does is an extra encryption/decryption overhead. I'm not familiar with Java or Spring framework, may I ask you a question - does your app contain some static files - javascript assets, images, etc? Using nginx to serve that type of content directly proxying only the requests that should be handled by Java code  will give you significant performance benefit.

Comment: You're so right, could you share a configuration example?

Comment: Sure, but it is probably not a good idea to do it with the comment, especially since only inline markdown is supported within the comment but not the multiline. Maybe you ask for it as another question, something like "How to serve the static content for the Spring Boot app with nginx" providing your current nginx configuration?

Comment: Found an example in one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496857/deploed-spring-boot-application-on-tomcat-create-bad-urls/64500679#64500679).